# Why does the "entanglement entropy" provide a necessary and sufficient condition for bipartite entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

The usual argument I’ve seen is that, well, if you have some separable (unentangled) pure state $|\psi\rangle= |\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle $ then $\text{Tr}_2 (|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|) = |\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_1 |$ and therefore the entropy of entanglement $S_E$ between subsystem $1$ and $2$ is $0$ as
$$
S_E(\rho, 1|2)= S_N(\rho_1),
$$
where $S_N$ is the Von Neumann entropy and $\rho_1$ is the reduced density matrix describing subsystem $1$. There is no doubt about the above.

**Now, why is this a reversible statement?** Why if $S_E(\rho, 1|2) \neq 0$ *then* subsystem $1$ is entangled with subsystem $2$.

Comment: This is a question of logic: if A always implies B then the falseness of B always implies the falseness of A.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a bipartite system and let $\rho$ denote a pure state density operator with reduced density matrices $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$.

OP proved that if $\rho$ is a product state, then $S_{\mathrm E} (\rho) = 0$. By modus tollens it follows that if $S_{\mathrm E}(\rho) \neq 0$ for a bipartite pure $\rho$, then $\rho$ cannot be a product state (and thus both subsystems are entangled).

However, we can prove an even stronger result:

Note that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are pure if and only if $\rho$ is a product state, which can be shown using the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition). Moreover, the [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy#Properties) of a density matrix is zero if and only if it is pure.

Consequently, the entropy of entanglement of a pure bipartite state $\rho$ is zero if and only if it is a product state:

$$S_{\mathrm E} (\rho) =  0  \Longleftrightarrow \rho = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2  $$